# How did Henry die if he rushed to hospital in time and was wheelchaired?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-time-travelers-wife

In The Time Traveler's Wife, at Alba's 5th birthday her father Henry got shot by deer hunters.

We can see him rushing to the hospital and the doctor assures his wife that they will fix the leg and finally he is wheelchaired. But then how did he die?

Comment: you might want to edit your post as it's unclear what you're asking. Are you asking why he was in a wheelchair or why he died?

Comment: You are confused with two scenes, he got into wheelchair due to hypothermia and he got shot way later and died without reaching any hospital.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A wheelchair-bound Henry (at his max. age) goes back in time, accidentally gets shot by his father-in-law who's deer hunting; then returns to his proper time and dies before help can arrive.  At the time he's shot, Henry appears to be standing in the woods but he might just be sitting in the snow.  The father-in-law remarks that he doesn't see any tracks (indicating Henry didn't take any steps).

The incident of going to the hospital pre-dates getting shot and is re: treating for hypothermia in which use of his leg(s) is lost (in the book they're amputated; in the movie they saved CGI costs by just making one(?) crippled).

Answer (score 0):

They are two different scenes.

When he is shot, he dies very shortly thereafter, never having received any proper medical assistance.